# Python Panel Button Callback Function

Tags: python, pandas, widget, panel-pyviz

So, I'm trying to build a Dashboard with the python [Panel](https://panel.pyviz.org/index.html) library, so far I have not had problems creating interaction between some widgets and plots except for the [Button Widget](https://panel.pyviz.org/reference/widgets/Button.html#gallery-button). I have two functions which I want to be executed when a respective button is clicked.

The first one is a function to get some data into a Dataframe, it's something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import panel as pn
import hvplot.pandas

pn.extension()


def update_df(event, save=True):

    # Read data from csv file
    df = pd.read_csv('../my_file.csv')

    # Check if data is up to date
    if df.index[-i] == pd.to_datetime(date.today()):
        return df
    else:
        # This function updates the data from the last date to the current date
        df = get_data(df) 

    if save:
        df.to_csv('../my_file.csv')

    return df

# Next is to create the button
update_button = pn.widgets.Button(name='Update DF')

# According to the docs, the on_click method should be enough to accomplish my purpose 
update_button.on_click(update_df)

# When the button is clicked nothing happens... 
pn.Row(update_button)
```

I also tried `update_button.param.watch(update_df, 'clicks')` but obtained no different result.

The other function I want to be triggered when a button is clicked is more complex because involves more widgets, it is like this:

```
# This function will be dependent of a list of variables and a integer value
# This values will be taken from two widgets
list_vars = pn.widgets.CrossSelector(value=['A'], options=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])
interval = pn.widgets.DiscreteSlider(value=120, options=[365, 240, 120, 60, 30])

# And of course, the button that will make the callback to the function
optimize_button = pn.widgets.Button(name='Optimize!', button_type='primary')

# Next, the function itself
@pn.depends(list_vars.param.value, interval.param.value)
def optimize_vars(list_vars, interval):
    # The data is sliced by the variables of interest
    temp = df[list_vars]

    # A Monte Carlo simulation is made with the temp data, three arrays are returned, 
    # they have shape n x len(list_vars)
    n = 50000
    bsr, brr, mop = simulation(temp, interval, n)

    # A markdown table in form of string is created, it contains mainly some statistics about 
    # the arrays returned by the simulation
    m = markdown_table(bsr, brr, mop)

    # A holoviews Scatterplot is created
    plot = mcs_plot(bsr, brr, mop)

    return m, plot

# The layout is created, I want it to show the control widgets as well as the markdown table and the 
# plot returned by the function above defined, but again, when the button is clicked nothing happens! 
pn.Row(pn.Column(pn.Row('# Variables', align='center'), 
                 pn.Column(interval, align='center'), 
                 pn.Column(list_vars, align='center'), 
                 pn.Column(optimize_button, align='center'), 
                 pn.Column(m, align='center')), 
       plot)
```

So, the obvious question is ¿what am I missing? ¿how can I achieve the callbacks with button widgets?

Answer (score 1):

The way to define a callback is ok, though I do not see why you define a callback with a keyword `save` and a return value.

The following simplified code is triggering the callback when the button is pressed:

```
# the key word 'save' can never be changed when the callback is triggered.
def update(event, save=True): 
    print(event)
    return save # which variable should take and use the return value? The calling Button?

button = pn.widgets.Button(name='Button')
button.on_click(update)

# using a bokeh server inside the notebook the print statements in the method 'update' are displayed,
# Otherwise the print statements are not visible in the outout cell
layout = button
layout.app()
```

The output is:

```
<bokeh.server.server.Server at 0x29194b0e6c8>
Event(what='value', name='clicks', obj=Button(clicks=1), cls=<class 'panel.widgets.button.Button'>, old=0, new=1, type='changed')
```

Comment: Ok, got it, I removed the `save` keyword and it finally worked.